# Java compiling wrong old file

Tags: virtual, bufferedimage

I have a java app that runs an infinite while loop. When I click run on eclipse it seems to be reverting to old code that I have changed. The thing is, when I build it updates at random times. The latest time I added System.exit(). I changed the code and it still exits. I have also tried this program in C#. I feel that I am somehow confusing the language runtime with the infinite while loop. The program works on a series of changing boolean values. The main action I am looking at the erratic behavior (this was what was happening before I added System.exit()) is in a method that iterates pixels in a BufferedImage. I am running Ubuntu 14.10. I have tried making a new project and pasting the same code (could it be invisible chars somehow?) I am very confused and would be happy if someone could help.

```
while(true){
if (bool1 && !exe.isSeparate(image))
{
    // change boolean values
    // did run System.exit(0)
}
if (bool2 && !exe.isSeparate(image))
{
    // change boolean values
    // did run System.exit(0)
}
}

boolean isSeparate(BufferedImage image)
{
    int x = touchingX;
    boolean first = false, second = false, third = false;
    int startAt = this.getYStart(image);
    for (int y = startAt; y < startAt + 150; y++)
    {
        Color pixel = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
        if (!(pixel.getRed() == 255 && pixel.getGreen() == 255 && pixel.getBlue() == 255)
                && !(pixel.getRed() == 0 && pixel.getGreen() == 68 && pixel.getBlue() == 125))
        {
            if (!first)
            {
                first = true;
            }
            if (first && second && !third)
            {
                third = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (first && !second)
            {
                second = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (first && second && third)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my question. Ironically, it was a logic error.